# when a test failed nightwatch skip the next ones?

Tags: javascript, testing, nightwatch.js

i am using nightwatch VRT , and when a test fail,he skips all tests that come after that.
i tried adding ***end_session_on_fail : false,*** and ***skip_testcases_on_fail: false,*** to my nightwatch.conf.js but it does not change anything :

```
test_settings: {
    end_session_on_fail : false,
    default: {   
      skip_testcases_on_fail: false,
      globals: {
        visual_regression_settings: {
            generate_screenshot_path: generateScreenshotFilePath,
            latest_screenshots_path: "screenshots/VRT/latest",
            latest_suffix: "",
            baseline_screenshots_path: "screenshots/VRT/baseline",
            baseline_suffix: "",
            diff_screenshots_path: "screenshots/VRT/diff",
            diff_suffix: "",
            threshold: 0,
            prompt: false,
            always_save_diff_screenshot: false
        }
      },
```

Any ideas please ?

Comment: Did you try adding skip_testcases_on_fail: false, outside the default object, and just below end_session_on_fail?

Answer (score 0):

You have to write `end_session_on_fail : false,` before default for it to work. So now your `nightwatch.conf.js` file should look something like this:

```js
test_settings: {
  end_session_on_fail: false,
  skip_testcases_on_fail: false,
  default: {
    globals: {
      visual_regression_settings: {
        generate_screenshot_path: generateScreenshotFilePath,
        latest_screenshots_path: "screenshots/VRT/latest",
        latest_suffix: "",
        baseline_screenshots_path: "screenshots/VRT/baseline",
        baseline_suffix: "",
        diff_screenshots_path: "screenshots/VRT/diff",
        diff_suffix: "",
        threshold: 0,
        prompt: false,
        always_save_diff_screenshot: false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Already tried this , but its not working :/